# HTML link is un-clickable for some reason

Tags: html, hyperlink, href

I am designing a website, I am using a text link(href) as logo, but for some reason it is not clickable. I inspected it with chrome and didn't find anything'suspicious. I even tried changing the html code, nothing works. Can someone shed light on this? Thank you.

The link is the logo in the top left corner, WhatAboutHTML

Here is the link: http://whatabouthtml.com
below is the code:

```
<div class="logo">
     <h1 style="font-size: 24px;line-height: normal; margin-bottom: 0px;">
        <a href="http://whatabouthtml.com/" title="What About HTML" rel="home">What About HTML</a>
    </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Always provide the relevant code and suitably concise, working example of your problem.

Comment: Your wrapper div is overlapping the div that your link is in. Thus, it's not clickable because the browser believes it is not accessible.

Comment: @Mike K can you be more specific, I do not understand, code example will be best,thank you

Comment: Ok. First off, why is your `wrapper` div 1180px, and more importantly, why do you have the `!important` declaration? Using `!important` is strongly discouraged. If you need to use a grid system, look into Bootstrap or 960 Grid System.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the following to your code:

```
#nav {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Or put you nav in the right place. Which is inside the wrapper.

Comment: P.S: the code is a mess

Comment: @ Danny van Holten Thank you, it works. But is there a way to clean up the code so I don't have to use the above css rules, I am trying to code clean HTML. Thank you.